# Python- when dividing value always prints 0

Tags: python

```
g == float(minute_wt_amount)/3.0
print (g)
```

Specifically this line, `g == float(minute_wt_amount)/3.0` always prints the value of zero, even though `minute_wt_amount` equals `30`. Does anyone have any suggestions

Comment: What is `minute_wt_amount`? How can `print(g)` work when you typed `g ==` instead of `g =`? This problem isn't at all reproducible.

Comment: Replace == with =

Answer (score 0):

`==` is the equality check, you need to use `=` for assignment.

```
g = float(minute_wt_amount)/3.0
print (g)
```